# Laravel problem with image url when transferring files from one pc to another

Tags: laravel

With another person we had developed a project in Laravel and when that person sent it to me, the images are not displayed, the images if they are stored in folders in the project and the urls in the database are correct, when I send the project again also had the same problem.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

indicates that the routes were created.

This is the code that saves the image in a folder within the project and the url in the database which works well
Controller:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        $dataCard=request()->except('_token');

        if($request->hasFile('card_img')){
            $dataCard['card_img']=$request->file('card_img')->store('cards-Img','public');
        }
        carta::insert($dataCard);
        return redirect('cards');

    }
```

he image url is saved like this:
    cards-Img/H0mopUhgWQTn0N25jx5UZJjBvevP74by4kXbIwvI.jpeg

The view where I display the images does not show the image but does load the name in the alt from the database

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
@foreach($cards as $card)
<div class="form-group">
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="{{asset('storage').'/'.$card->card_img}}" alt="{{$card->card_nom}}">
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach

</div>
@endsection
```

We do not understand what is happening, how can we solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my friend. I don't know how to solve it but i can give you a work around!

In config/filesystems.php change the root folder path.

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('storage/'),
        ],
```

Then in your controller

```
$dataCard=request()->except('_token');

if($request->hasFile('card_img')){
      $imageName = time().'_CardImg.'.$request->file('card_img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $request->file('card_img')->move(public_path().'/storage/cards-Img/', $imageName);
}
carta::insert($imageName);
return redirect('cards');
```

Then to access the image on your view.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
@foreach($cards as $card)
<div class="form-group">
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="{{ asset('storage/cards-Img/'.$card->card_img)}}" alt="{{$card->card_nom}}">
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach

</div>
@endsection
```

Now everything will be saved in the public storage folder. So this works without the `php artisan storage:link` command. I hope you find it usefull!